# Parsing JSON output to variable in bash using jq filters

Tags: json, jq

I have a query like this:

```bash
curl -s \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $API_TOKEN" \
--data "$(echo $PAYLOAD)" \
https://myapi/client/v4/graphql/ | jq .
```

... that produces output like this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "accounts": [
        {
          "magicTransitTunnelTrafficAdaptiveGroups": [
            {
              "avg": {
                "bitRateFiveMinutes": 23360
              },
              "dimensions": {
                "datetimeFiveMinutes": "2022-12-30T09:00:00Z",
                "tunnelName": "nw-blue"
              }
            },
            {
              "avg": {
                "bitRateFiveMinutes": 8960
              },
              "dimensions": {
                "datetimeFiveMinutes": "2022-12-30T09:00:00Z",
                "tunnelName": "mtlab_gcp1"
              }
            },
            {
              "avg": {
                "bitRateFiveMinutes": 95493
              },
              "dimensions": {
                "datetimeFiveMinutes": "2022-12-30T09:00:00Z",
                "tunnelName": "Cherry_CBE_1"
              }
            },
            {
              "avg": {
                "bitRateFiveMinutes": 2968507
              },
              "dimensions": {
                "datetimeFiveMinutes": "2022-12-30T09:00:00Z",
                "tunnelName": "Cherry_VCB"
              }
            },
            {
              "avg": {
                "bitRateFiveMinutes": 10880
              },
              "dimensions": {
                "datetimeFiveMinutes": "2022-12-30T09:00:00Z",
                "tunnelName": "accelia-poc1"
              }
            },
            {
              "avg": {
                "bitRateFiveMinutes": 21227
              },
              "dimensions": {
                "datetimeFiveMinutes": "2022-12-30T09:00:00Z",
                "tunnelName": "mtlab_sr_pni"
              }
            },
            {
              "avg": {
                "bitRateFiveMinutes": 27627
              },
              "dimensions": {
                "datetimeFiveMinutes": "2022-12-30T09:00:00Z",
                "tunnelName": "mtlab-tme-gcp1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "errors": null
}
```

I want to parse all the `bitRateFiveMinutes` values, add them up, and stuff them into a variable for evaluation.  How do I do this using the `jq -r` option? I looked at the examples on https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/, but I could not determine what to use.  It looks like there is a built-in operator `+` that might do the addition for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm taking a bit of a shortcut to avoid having to write out the complete path to the wanted values.  I put the values in an array and then I run it through `add` to sum it up:

```bash
curl -s ... |
jq '[ .data[][][][][].avg.bitRateFiveMinutes ] | add'
```

Given the example in your question, this would output `3156054`.  You don't need to use `jq` with its `-r` option here, as integers are not string encoded.

A more verbose `jq` command would possibly look like

```bash
curl -s ... |
jq '.data.viewer.accounts |
    map(.magicTransitTunnelTrafficAdaptiveGroups |
        map(.avg.bitRateFiveMinutes) | add) | add'
```

This first computes the sum over all entries of each `magicTransitTunnelTrafficAdaptiveGroups` array and then adds these partial sums together.  In your example, there's only a single of these inner arrays.

Getting the result into a shell variable is then a matter of running the pipeline in a command substitution and assigning it to a variable:

```bash
avgsum=$(
    curl -s ... |
    jq '[ .data[][][][][].avg.bitRateFiveMinutes ] | add'
)
```

---

Also note that your `--data "$(echo $PAYLOAD)"` is better written as `--data "$PAYLOAD"`, unless you need to have the shell perform splitting and filename globbing on the unquoted value of `$PAYLOAD`, and `echo` to do its special processing of `\n`, `\t`, and `\\`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer.  This helped immensley!

Comment: I did try to remove echo from the curl query, but got this error:

jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)

Comment: @JeffSani That's an error from `jq`, and I don't think that has anything to do with the `echo`. Look at the result of the `curl` request and whether the response looks very different from what you presented in the question (an array be empty, or other bits may be missing). If you still can't figure out what's happening, consider opening a new question. I'm unfamiliar with the service you're accessing with `curl`, so I can't say what the expected behaviour would be.

Comment: I was reviewing your answer again and wanted to know how you arrived at 5 brackets "[][][][][]" to get to the object and value I needed? Is it as simple as adding the curly brackets?